# SSIS packages failing to load in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, bids

I have a problem when trying to load an SSIS package in VS 2008. In the about it says it has "SQL Server Integration Services" installed but on loading a package I get a message that says:

> Microsoft Vistual Studio is unable to load this document:
>
> To design
> Integration Services packages in Business Intelligence Development
> Studio, Integration Services has to be installed by one of these
> editions of SQL Server 2008: Standard, Enterprise, Developer or
> Evaluation. To install Integration Services, run SQL Server Setup and
> select Integration Services.

I thought maybe it was a version problem so I thought I'd look at a new Intergation Services project to play spot the difference. However when I told visual studio to create a new IS project (which was in the list quite happily) it created it and then gave me the above error message again.

To give some idea about my environment I have several version of Visual Studio (2k5, 2k8, 2k10) and several version of SQL server (2k5, 2k8) so I don't know if there is some confusion between versions...

The other thing that I am wondering is if there is a problem with what order things got installed in (ie my VS2008 wasn't installed when SSIS stuff was installed).

I am hoping there is a simple approach to this that won't mean reinstalling things. I can go to our IT to ask them to try to get it working but that would take some time. If it does come to that though I'd like to have some idea of what I should ask them to install since it does seem to be all installed currently...

So if anybody can either a) help me work out precisely what components are installed and what is missing that would be great. Bonus points for helping fix it without needing the install media...

**Edit**: A thought occurs to me. Coudl it be that I only have 2005 Integration Services installed? If so how can I determine that? And I still am not sure why VS is behaving as it is and letting me create a project but no SSIS in it, even if they were older versions...

**Edit**: Also it seems that if I load up VS 2005 I can create IS projects but of course can't load up the newer SSIS packages, I assume because they are from a newer version maybe...

**Edit:** Version information for SSIS in VS 2008:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
```

Comment: Can you connect with Integration Services through the SSMS (Connect -> Integration Services...)? You can check what's your SSIS version there (and check connection as well, two flies with one stone or something).

Comment: @Josien: I don't seem to have that option at all! I should note that it is basically just the BIDS that I need to get working. I don't actually have a full blown sql with IS installed on this local computer...

Comment: Ah, okay. Could you copy the product details on "SQL Server Integration Services" from the 'About Microsoft Visual Studio' window? You can check your version of SSIS there (9.x is 2005, 10.x is 2008, 10.50 is 2008 R2...)

Comment: @Josien: Its `Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )` (I'll edit it into the question in a bit. For what its worth I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling BIDS but still no success. :( Is there a way to check what version my dtsx files are created for (I assume its somewhere in the xml but not sure where)...

Answer (score 1):

The following line can tell you the version of the package:

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">3</DTS:Property>
```

3 is for 2008, 2 is 2005 and 6 is 2012.

By the way, how patched is your system? The 10.0.1600.22 does sound like the original installation of 2008. Try to install [SP3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2546951) and the latest [cumulative update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2629969) - this will bring your installation to 10.00.5788 and the issue might go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you previously had the components from a Express 2008 installation, and then you install an Standard, Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation, instead of actually installing a new instance/components (probably you see Integration Services grayed out) use the Upgrade option of the SQL Server 2008 setup, and then VS will load perfectly the DTSX file.